# Tribonacci number program doesnt return false

Tags: c++

For each number read from the standard input the program should print YES if it is a Tribonacci number and NO otherwise. What am I doing wrong in my program, it prints YES, but it wont print NO when the number is not a tribonacci number. For example when number is 45, it should print no.

Tribonacci number formula

```
T0=0
T1=1
T2=2
Tn=Tn-1 + Tn-2 + Tn-3 (for n>2)
```

```cpp
using namespace std;

bool isTrib(int n) {
    if(n==0 || n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if(n > 2) {
        int trib = isTrib(n-1)+isTrib(n-2)+isTrib(n-3);
        if(trib == n) {
            return true;
        }
    }
   return false; 
}
   

int main()
{
    int n;
    while(cin>>n) {
        bool result = isTrib(n);
        cout << result;
        result == 1 ? cout << "YES" << endl : cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `int trib =  ...` rather be `bool trib = ...`?

Comment: *"For example when number is 45"* -- this gives you a quick way to make it easier for others to reproduce your result. Instead of getting user input, hardcode the problematic case for your **example** code. `int main() { int n = 45; /* Would be read from standard input */ bool result = isTrib(n); cout << (result ? "YES" : "NO") << endl; }`

Comment: Unable to reproduce your result. Your code tells me "NO" for 45 (and for every number over 3, for that matter).

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `int trib = isTrib(n-1)+isTrib(n-2)+isTrib(n-3);`, how exactly do you intend for the logic to work? Does `isTrib` *compute* Tribonacci numbers, or does it *test* for them? It cannot be both at once.

Comment: Also, try to think about the problem logically. Suppose we want to find out whether `45` is a Tribonacci number or not. **Why is it useful** to check whether `42`, `43` and `44` are Tribonacci numbers? Before writing the code, try to write out, in plain English sentences, a series of steps that you want the code to take in order to do the test. Then *make sure it makes sense* before trying to write the code, by trying to use it - **exactly** - to test some values, by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're mixing two things: actual tribonacci numbers and "true"/"false" answer to question "whether N is tribonacci", for example variable `trib` in your code can be either 0, 1, 2 or 3, it cannot take any other values, but you're trying to compare it with real number, which is apples to oranges

here is fixed version:

```
bool isTrib(int n) {
    if(n==0 || n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 1;
    int n3 = 2;
    
    int trib = n1 + n2 + n3;
    while (trib <= n) {
        if (trib == n) return true;
        
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        n3 = trib;
        trib = n1 + n2 + n3;
    }
    return false;
}
   

int main()
{
    int n;
    while(cin>>n) {
        bool result = isTrib(n);
        cout << (result ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can this not be done with this formula? `isTrib(n-1)+isTrib(n-2)+isTrib(n-3);`

Comment: @squnk no, it cannot be done with this formula, it has no mathematical sense

Comment: Let's consider a simpler example: I can compute the nth even number, `even(n)`, as `even(n-1) + 2` (with an appropriate base case). Now I want to implement `isEven`, and find out whether `45` is even. Do you understand why it makes no sense at all, to test whether `44` is even, and then add `2` to the result of that boolean test?

Comment: The approach in the fixed code is to generate Tribonacci numbers, in ascending order, and see *whether we find* the specified `n` this way exactly, or skip past it instead. Since we know the sequence is ascending, once we exceed `n` we can never find `n`.